# how to view logo depending upon screen resolution?

Tags: android, imageview, screen-resolution

Hi I created one medical app. it,s working fine. i placed one logo in center of the app screen my logo size height and width is 70x70 and my emulator screen resolution is 900 x 800 if i change my screen resolution i wish to change my logo size also dynamic. this is my doubt how to set logo depending upon the screen resolution?

code:

```
public class ImageviewAppActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView img; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        img =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagetest);
        img.setMaxWidth(20);
        img.setMaxHeight(100);


    }
}
```

xml: main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagetest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try using dip instead of dp/px?

Comment: @eric.itzhak no brother how to use dp/px?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look,I think you should set size of logog according to diffrent resolution
then try to use

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
float density = metrics.density;
```

density is float and its value changed as per screen size...

so,if you have

```
240*320 density is 0.5
320*480 density is 1.0
480*800 density is 1.5
```

and set size using density like ,    `img.setMaxHeight(density*100);`

and also put multiple screen supports in manifest file...[Multiple Screen Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can play with the different screen resolution by the dpi.
In your project you can create different drawable folder that allow you to put in your project different images with different resolution that will be loaded automatically from the device depending the screen resolution.

```
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
```